# Are the delete operations triggering java gc

Tags: cassandra

I have a special use case. If i have many deletes against several particular tables with no match on the primary keys, will that cause performance issue to my db? I noticed some GC pauses recently. Are they related?

I found an "if exists" clause is supported for delete. Is it good to use it for this problem? Is it good to use it for all my other delete operations?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Can you please share data model of the data that causes problems. And what delete statements are you using on them. It might be that you are reading a lot of tombstones because of the data model that you have. if not exists is not supposed to be used with usual workload. It's for the 1% of the traffic.

Comment: We are using django orm. There is nothing special about the model. Just assume it is a basic table, with 1 column as the primary key. I just want to the if there are significant differences in terms of tombstone handling during deletion when there is a pk match vs no pk match(the record does not exist). Also if using "if_exists" helps in this condition. Thanks.